# Generic parameter reusability

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have two different methods

```
public static void printRoutes(List<Optional<String>> routes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
        if(routes.get(i).isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("Output #" + (i+1) + ": "+routes.get(i).get());
```

and

```
public static void printRoutes(List<Optional<Integer>> routes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
        if(routes.get(i).isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("Output #" + (i+1) + ": "+routes.get(i).get());
```

As you can see they are basically the same but the parameter type.
Since I am just printing them which means use the ".toString()" method I think there should be a way to use the same method for both.

I tried

```
public static void printRoutes(List<Optional<T super Object>> lengths)
```

and

```
public static void printRoutes(List<Optional<T extends Object>> lengths)
```

but it doesn't work,
Is there a way to do it? or you can't use generics in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to declare the type parameter `T`; and the `super Object` or `extends Object` is unnecessary:

```
public static <T> void printDistances(List<Optional<T>> lengths)
```

See [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

They can be anything, so you can write:

```
public static void printDistances(List<? extends Optional<?>> lengths)
```

which is shortcut for

```
public static void printDistances(List<? extends Optional<? extends Object>> lengths)
```

since everything inherits from `Object`.

Notice this will also do without introducing generic parameters.

Comment: I used the other response and worked, thank you for your help @Andronicus

Comment: @DavidMarciel this answer avoids an unnecessary type parameter.

Comment: Your parameter of type `List<Optional<?>>` will not accept an argument of type `List<Optional<String>>` or `List<Optional<Integer>>`. To do that, your parameter should have type `List<? extends Optional<?>>`.